# How to use pagedlist with post method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, viewmodel, pagedlist

I have a question about PagedList. I have a grid of data that I can filter using dropdownlist and checkbox. It works well. I use "PagedList", which allows me to display only 10 row per page in my grid of data. It works well when I don't use filter. When I select an item in my dropdownlist for example, the filter works well in the first page but if I click on the 2nd page the filter doesn't work anymore. To filter data, I use method Post and ViewModel. What can I do?
Thanks!
Here is my view:

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Missions", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <section>
            <h3>Localisation</h3>
            @*
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DirGeoSelected, "Direction geo", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-8" })
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DirGeoSelected, Model.DirGeoList, htmlAttributes: new { onchange = "form.submit();", @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DirGeoSelected, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            *@
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProgrammeIdSelected, "Programme", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProgrammeIdSelected, Model.Programme, "All", htmlAttributes: new { onchange = "form.submit();", @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProgrammeIdSelected, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CountryIdSelected, "Pays", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryIdSelected, Model.Country, "All", htmlAttributes: new { onchange = "form.submit();", @class = "form-control"/*, data_url = Url.Action("GetCountries")*/ })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountryIdSelected, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

        </section>
        <section>
            <h3>Personne</h3>
        </section>
        <section>
            @*
                <h3>Date</h3>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        @Html.TextBox("SelectedDateStart", new {@class = "datepicker"})
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        @Html.TextBox("SelectedDateEnd", new { @class = "datepicker"})
                    </div>
                </div>
            *@
        </section>
        <section>
            <h3>Type</h3>
            <div class="col-md-12 form-check">
                @Html.CheckBox("Support", true, new { onchange = "form.submit();", @class = "form-check-input" })
                @Html.Label("Mission Support", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.CheckBox("Autre", true, new { onchange = "form.submit();", @class = "form-check-input" })
                @Html.Label("Autre", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h3>Priority</h3>
            <div class="col-md-12 form-check">
                @Html.CheckBox("Support", true, new { onchange = "form.submit();", @class = "form-check-input" })
                @Html.Label("Mission Support", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.CheckBox("Autre", true, new { onchange = "form.submit();", @class = "form-check-input" })
                @Html.Label("Autre", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h3>Décision</h3>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Decison)
            </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h3>Equipe</h3>
            @*
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DirectionIdSelected, "Direction", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DirectionIdSelected, Model.DirectionList, htmlAttributes: new { onchange = "form.submit();", @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DirectionIdSelected, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            *@
        </section>
    }
</nav>
<div id="content" class="container">
    <h2>Missions</h2>
    @*  @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Missions", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        @Html.TextBox("searching")
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    }
    *@
    <p class="newmission">
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Nouvelle Mission" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create", "Missions")'" />
    </p>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th class="col-md-2">
                @Html.ActionLink("Pays", "Index",
                new { SortOrder = Model.SortCountry})
            </th>
            <th class="col-md-1">
                @Html.ActionLink("Date", "Index",
                new { SortOrder = ViewBag.ListorderDate,
                    /*SelectedDesk = ViewBag.ListorderPays,
                    SelectedProgramme = ViewBag.ListorderDate,*/
                })
            </th>
            <th class="col-md-2">
                Personne
            </th>
            <th class="col-md-10">
                Missions
            </th>
            <th class="col-md-10">
            </th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.OnePageOfMissions)
        {
            <tr>
                <td class="col-md-1">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.decision)
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-2">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.organization_hi_country.name_en)
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-1">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.asked_date)
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-2"></td>
                <td class="col-md-10">
                    <span class="typemission">Mission</span> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.list_type.name_en, new { @class = "typemission" }) : @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.list_nature.name_en, new { @class = "typemission" })
                    <div>
                        <!-- les boutons d'actions -->
                        <a href="#@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id)" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id)">details</a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- le contenu masqué -->
                    <section id="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id)" class="collapse">
                        <div class="well">
                            <p><em>Statut: </em>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.list_statut.name_en)</p>
                            <p><em>Durée: </em>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.duration) jours</p>
                            <p><em>Flexibilité: </em>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.list_flexibility.name_en) </p>
                            <p><em>Priorité: </em>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.list_priority.name_en) </p>
                            <p><em>Commentaires: </em>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.comments) </p>
                        </div>
                    </section>

                </td>
                <td class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Create", new { id = item.id })
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model.OnePageOfMissions, page => Url.Action("Index", new { searchItem = ViewBag.searchItem, page }))
    </table>
```

Here is my controller:

```
namespace MissionsDF.Controllers
```

{
public class MissionsController : Controller
{
private Missions_devEntities db = new Missions_devEntities();

```
    // GET: /Missions/
    public ActionResult Index(string SortOrder, int? page)
    {
        IndexViewModel model = new IndexViewModel();
        //Affichage de la liste des Programmes
        model.Programme = GetProgrammes();
        //Tri des pays:
        model.SortCountry = String.IsNullOrEmpty(SortOrder) ? "ListorderPays_desc" : "";
        model.missionsList = db.missions_supportmission.ToList();
        switch (SortOrder)
        {
            case "ListorderPays_desc":
                model.missionsList = model.missionsList.OrderByDescending(s => s.organization_hi_country.name_en);
                break;
            default:
                model.missionsList = model.missionsList.OrderBy(s => s.organization_hi_country.name_en);
                break;
        }
        //Pagination
        var pageNumber = page ?? 1; // if no page was specified in the querystring, default to the first page (1)
        var onePageOfMissions = model.missionsList.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 10); // will only contain 10 products max because of the pageSize(equel to 10)
        model.OnePageOfMissions = onePageOfMissions;

        //Ischecked
        var allDecisions = db.list_decision.ToList();//returns List<list_decision>
        var checkBoxListItems = new List<CheckBoxListItem>(); //nouvelle instance de la classe checkboxlist
        foreach (var decison in allDecisions)
        {//On assigne les valeurs "id", "display" et "is checked" à la variable checkboxlistitem
            checkBoxListItems.Add(new CheckBoxListItem()
            {
                ID = decison.decision_id,
                Display = decison.name_en,
                IsChecked = false //On the add view, no decision are selected by default
            });
        }
        model.Decison = checkBoxListItems;                                   
        return View(model);
    }
    private List<SelectListItem> GetProgrammes()
    {
        return db.organization_programme
                 .Select(x => new SelectListItem
                 {
                     Value = x.prog_id,
                     Text = x.name_en
                 })
                 .ToList();
    }

    //POST: /Missions/Index
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IndexViewModel model, int? page)
    {
        
        //Filtres sur Programme et Country
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var pageNumber = page ?? 1;
            var selecteddecision = model.Decison.Where(x => x.IsChecked).Select(x => x.ID);
            //Si selecteddecision n'est pas null            
            //Si Programme n'est pas null et que country est null
            if (!(selecteddecision.IsAny()))
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ProgrammeIdSelected) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.CountryIdSelected))
                {                                                 
                        var onePageOfMissions = db.missions_supportmission
                                    .Where(a => a.programme_id == model.ProgrammeIdSelected)
                                    .OrderBy(a => a.programme_id)
                                    .Select(s => s).ToPagedList(pageNumber, 10);

                        model.OnePageOfMissions = onePageOfMissions;
                }
                //Si Country est null 
                else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.CountryIdSelected))
                {
                    model.OnePageOfMissions = db.missions_supportmission
                                        .Where(a => a.country_id == model.CountryIdSelected)
                                        .OrderBy(a => a.country_id)
                                        .Select(s => s).ToPagedList(pageNumber, 10);
                    if (model.missionsList != null)
                    {

                        var onePageOfMissions = model.missionsList.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 10);
                        model.OnePageOfMissions = onePageOfMissions;
                    }
                }
                //Sinon on affiche tout 
                else
                {
                    model.OnePageOfMissions = db.missions_supportmission
                   .OrderBy(a => a.programme_id)
                   .Select(s => s).ToPagedList(pageNumber, 10);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var item in selecteddecision)
                {
                    //Si Programme n'est pas null et que country est null
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ProgrammeIdSelected) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.CountryIdSelected))
                    {
                        model.OnePageOfMissions = db.missions_supportmission
                                        .Where(a => a.programme_id == model.ProgrammeIdSelected)
                                        .Where(a => a.decision == item)
                                        .OrderBy(a => a.programme_id)
                                        .Select(s => s).ToPagedList(pageNumber, 10);
                        var onePageOfMissions = model.missionsList.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 10);
                        model.OnePageOfMissions = onePageOfMissions;
                    }
                    //Si Country est null 
                    else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.CountryIdSelected))
                    {
                        model.OnePageOfMissions = db.missions_supportmission
                                            .Where(a => a.country_id == model.CountryIdSelected)
                                            .Where(a => a.decision == item)
                                            .OrderBy(a => a.country_id)
                                            .Select(s => s).ToPagedList(pageNumber, 10);
                        var onePageOfMissions = model.missionsList.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 10);
                        model.OnePageOfMissions = onePageOfMissions;
                    }
                    //Sinon on affiche tout 
                    else
                    {
                        model.OnePageOfMissions = db.missions_supportmission
                       .Where(a => a.decision == item)
                       .OrderBy(a => a.programme_id)
                       .Select(s => s).ToPagedList(pageNumber, 10);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        var allDecisions = db.list_decision.ToList();//returns List<list_decision>
            var checkBoxListItems = new List<CheckBoxListItem>(); //nouvelle instance de la classe checkboxlist
            foreach (var decison in allDecisions)
            {//On assigne les valeurs "id", "display" et "is checked" à la variable checkboxlistitem
                checkBoxListItems.Add(new CheckBoxListItem()
                {
                    ID = decison.decision_id,
                    Display = decison.name_en,
                });
            }
            model.Decison = checkBoxListItems;
            //Affichage en cascade liste de programmes + liste pays
            model.Programme = GetProgrammes();
            model.Country = db.organization_hi_country
            .Where(a => a.prog_id == model.ProgrammeIdSelected)
            .Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.country_id,
                Text = x.name_en
            }).ToList();
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain purpose of 3 different form tags? you won't be able to share values across form tags, implicitly.

Comment: I also did not see any use of ViewBag in server side code. I will recommend use of TempData to share data between subsequent requests from same page.

Comment: can you show me an example?

Comment: Only the first form tag is useful. I deleted the other form tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I found the solution. I decided to use only get method.

In my controller I have this:

```
       public ActionResult Index(string SortOrder, int? page, string ProgrammeIdSelected)
    {
        IndexViewModel model = new IndexViewModel();
        //Affichage de la liste des Programmes
        model.Programme = GetProgrammes();
        //Tri des pays:
        model.SortCountry = String.IsNullOrEmpty(SortOrder) ? "ListorderPays_desc" : "";
        model.ProgrammeIdSelected = ProgrammeIdSelected;
        model.missionsList = db.missions_supportmission.ToList();
        switch (SortOrder)
        {
            case "ListorderPays_desc":
                model.missionsList = model.missionsList.OrderByDescending(s => s.organization_hi_country.name_en);
                break;
            default:
                model.missionsList = model.missionsList.OrderBy(s => s.organization_hi_country.name_en);
                break;
        }
        //Pagination
        var pageNumber = page ?? 1; // if no page was specified in the querystring, default to the first page (1)
        var onePageOfMissions = model.missionsList.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 10); // will only contain 10 products max because of the pageSize(equel to 10)
        model.OnePageOfMissions = onePageOfMissions;

            //Ischecked
        var allDecisions = db.list_decision.ToList();//returns List<list_decision>
        var checkBoxListItems = new List<CheckBoxListItem>(); //nouvelle instance de la classe checkboxlist
        foreach (var decison in allDecisions)
        {//On assigne les valeurs "id", "display" et "is checked" à la variable checkboxlistitem
            checkBoxListItems.Add(new CheckBoxListItem()
            {
                ID = decison.decision_id,
                Display = decison.name_en,
                IsChecked = false //On the add view, no decision are selected by default
            });
        }

        //Si Programme n'est pas null et que country est null
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ProgrammeIdSelected))
        {
            model.OnePageOfMissions = db.missions_supportmission
                            .Where(a => a.programme_id == ProgrammeIdSelected)
                            .OrderBy(a => a.programme_id)
                            .Select(s => s).ToPagedList(pageNumber, 10);
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

An d in my View I have this:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Missions", FormMethod.Get))
    {
    <section>
        <h3>Localisation</h3>
        @*
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DirGeoSelected, "Direction geo", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-8" })
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DirGeoSelected, Model.DirGeoList, htmlAttributes: new { onchange = "form.submit();", @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DirGeoSelected, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
        *@
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProgrammeIdSelected, "Programme", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProgrammeIdSelected, Model.Programme, "All", htmlAttributes: new {onchange = "form.submit();", @class = "form-control"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProgrammeIdSelected, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CountryIdSelected, "Pays", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryIdSelected, Model.Country, "All", htmlAttributes: new { onchange = "form.submit();", @class = "form-control"/*, data_url = Url.Action("GetCountries")*/ })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountryIdSelected, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>
        <section>
            <h3>Personne</h3>
        </section>
        <section>
            @*
            <h3>Date</h3>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    @Html.TextBox("SelectedDateStart", new {@class = "datepicker"})
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    @Html.TextBox("SelectedDateEnd", new { @class = "datepicker"})
                </div>
            </div>
            *@
        </section>
        <section>
            <h3>Type</h3>
            <div class="col-md-12 form-check">
                @Html.CheckBox("Support", true, new { onchange = "form.submit();", @class = "form-check-input" })
                @Html.Label("Mission Support", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.CheckBox("Autre", true, new { onchange = "form.submit();", @class = "form-check-input" })
                @Html.Label("Autre", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h3>Priority</h3>
            <div class="col-md-12 form-check">
                @Html.CheckBox("Support", true, new { onchange = "form.submit();", @class = "form-check-input" })
                @Html.Label("Mission Support", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.CheckBox("Autre", true, new { onchange = "form.submit();", @class = "form-check-input" })
                @Html.Label("Autre", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h3>Décision</h3>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Decison)
            </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h3>Equipe</h3>
            @*
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DirectionIdSelected, "Direction", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DirectionIdSelected, Model.DirectionList, htmlAttributes: new { onchange = "form.submit();", @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DirectionIdSelected, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            *@
        </section>

    }
</nav>
<div id="content" class="container">
    <h2>Missions</h2>
    @*  @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Missions", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        @Html.TextBox("searching")
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    }
    *@
    <p class="newmission">
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Nouvelle Mission" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create", "Missions")'" />
    </p>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th class="col-md-2">
                @Html.ActionLink("Pays", "Index",
                new { SortOrder = Model.SortCountry})
            </th>
            <th class="col-md-1">
                @Html.ActionLink("Date", "Index",
                new { SortOrder = ViewBag.ListorderDate,
                    /*SelectedDesk = ViewBag.ListorderPays,
                    SelectedProgramme = ViewBag.ListorderDate,*/
                })
            </th>
            <th class="col-md-2">
                Personne
            </th>
            <th class="col-md-10">
                Missions
            </th>
            <th class="col-md-10">
            </th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.OnePageOfMissions)
        {
            <tr>
                <td class="col-md-1">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.decision)
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-2">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.organization_hi_country.name_en)
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-1">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.asked_date)
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-2"></td>
                <td class="col-md-10">
                    <span class="typemission">Mission</span> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.list_type.name_en, new { @class = "typemission" }) : @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.list_nature.name_en, new { @class = "typemission" })
                    <div>
                        <!-- les boutons d'actions -->
                        <a href="#@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id)" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id)">details</a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- le contenu masqué -->
                    <section id="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id)" class="collapse">
                        <div class="well">
                            <p><em>Statut: </em>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.list_statut.name_en)</p>
                            <p><em>Durée: </em>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.duration) jours</p>
                            <p><em>Flexibilité: </em>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.list_flexibility.name_en) </p>
                            <p><em>Priorité: </em>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.list_priority.name_en) </p>
                            <p><em>Commentaires: </em>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.comments) </p>
                        </div>
                    </section>

                </td>
                <td class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Create", new { id = item.id })
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model.OnePageOfMissions, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, ProgrammeIdSelected = Model.ProgrammeIdSelected }))
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) If you are willing to revamp and modify your code both server side and client-side, I recommend following instructions mentioned at [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

2) In case you want to use Post method then, following changes may help you:

In your server side code, wherever you are assigning an object to 'ViewBag.searchItem', try using TempData["searchItem"] in place of it. And when accessing it on View page, also use TempData["searchItem"] wherever you are accessing 'ViewBag.searchItem' with appropriate casting.

While I suppose your server side code is working, client side html may work as shown below, with form tag wrapped around entire HTML..

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Missions", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <section>
        <h3>Localisation</h3>
        @*
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DirGeoSelected, "Direction geo", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-8" })
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DirGeoSelected, Model.DirGeoList, htmlAttributes: new { onchange = "form.submit();", @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DirGeoSelected, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        *@
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProgrammeIdSelected, "Programme", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProgrammeIdSelected, Model.Programme, "All", htmlAttributes: new { onchange = "form.submit();", @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProgrammeIdSelected, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CountryIdSelected, "Pays", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryIdSelected, Model.Country, "All", htmlAttributes: new { onchange = "form.submit();", @class = "form-control"/*, data_url = Url.Action("GetCountries")*/ })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountryIdSelected, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>
    <section>
        <h3>Personne</h3>
    </section>
    <section>
        @*
            <h3>Date</h3>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    @Html.TextBox("SelectedDateStart", new {@class = "datepicker"})
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    @Html.TextBox("SelectedDateEnd", new { @class = "datepicker"})
                </div>
            </div>
        *@
    </section>
    <section>
        <h3>Type</h3>
        <div class="col-md-12 form-check">
            @Html.CheckBox("Support", true, new { onchange = "form.submit();", @class = "form-check-input" })
            @Html.Label("Mission Support", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.CheckBox("Autre", true, new { onchange = "form.submit();", @class = "form-check-input" })
            @Html.Label("Autre", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h3>Priority</h3>
        <div class="col-md-12 form-check">
            @Html.CheckBox("Support", true, new { onchange = "form.submit();", @class = "form-check-input" })
            @Html.Label("Mission Support", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.CheckBox("Autre", true, new { onchange = "form.submit();", @class = "form-check-input" })
            @Html.Label("Autre", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h3>Décision</h3>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Decison)
        </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h3>Equipe</h3>
        @*
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DirectionIdSelected, "Direction", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DirectionIdSelected, Model.DirectionList, htmlAttributes: new { onchange = "form.submit();", @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DirectionIdSelected, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        *@
    </section> <div id="content" class="container">
<h2>Missions</h2>

<p class="newmission">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Nouvelle Mission" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create", "Missions")'" />
</p>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th class="col-md-2">
            @Html.ActionLink("Pays", "Index",
            new { SortOrder = Model.SortCountry})
        </th>
        <th class="col-md-1">
            @Html.ActionLink("Date", "Index",
            new { SortOrder = ViewBag.ListorderDate,
                /*SelectedDesk = ViewBag.ListorderPays,
                SelectedProgramme = ViewBag.ListorderDate,*/
            })
        </th>
        <th class="col-md-2">
            Personne
        </th>
        <th class="col-md-10">
            Missions
        </th>
        <th class="col-md-10">
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.OnePageOfMissions)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="col-md-1">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.decision)
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-2">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.organization_hi_country.name_en)
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-1">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.asked_date)
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-2"></td>
            <td class="col-md-10">
                <span class="typemission">Mission</span> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.list_type.name_en, new { @class = "typemission" }) : @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.list_nature.name_en, new { @class = "typemission" })
                <div>
                    <!-- les boutons d'actions -->
                    <a href="#@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id)" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id)">details</a>
                </div>
                <!-- le contenu masqué -->
                <section id="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id)" class="collapse">
                    <div class="well">
                        <p><em>Statut: </em>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.list_statut.name_en)</p>
                        <p><em>Durée: </em>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.duration) jours</p>
                        <p><em>Flexibilité: </em>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.list_flexibility.name_en) </p>
                        <p><em>Priorité: </em>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.list_priority.name_en) </p>
                        <p><em>Commentaires: </em>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.comments) </p>
                    </div>
                </section>

            </td>
            <td class="col-md-10">
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Create", new { id = item.id })
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model.OnePageOfMissions, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
</table>}
```

Comment: ViewBag;searchItem in my code is an example that I found in a tuto but I don't know how to apply it to my code. For example , what would you write in my code(view and controller)? Thanks

Comment: It means that you don't really have anything inside ViewBag.searchItem, so there is no point of using it. Now, if I were you, I would have redesigned the complete html to wrap everything inside the outer form tag and just use one post method to access all values associated inside form. I avoid using TempData and ViewData as much as I can.

Comment: and in my controller what should I change?